# Download file with progress bar in cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, download, progress-bar

I need to have a progress bar that responds to the percent complete of a download in cocoa. I think this might use things like NSProgressindicator and possibly NSTask. I'm not sure if theres an "official" method to download file in cocoa because up until now I just used curl with NSTask. Thanks for any replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm not sure if theres an "official" method to download file in cocoa …

There is: [NSURLDownload](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLDownload_Class/).

Answer (score 7):

Use [`NSURLConnection`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSURLConnection).  It has a [delegate](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-DontLinkElementID_17) property, which means it will tell you periodically that it has received more data (which you then have to save to a file yourself).  However, it also tells you when it has started retrieving the file, and if you're downloading a file over HTTP (which I think is a safe assumption), it will most likely have a [`Content-Length:` HTTP header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13), so you can know what to [set as the `maxValue`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSProgressIndicator_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000114-BCIBECAH) of your [`NSProgressIndicator`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSProgressIndicator_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  Then just [`incrementBy:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSProgressIndicator_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000114-BCIDFGAF) the size of the data [your connection has told you it just received](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-BAJGICCF).

If for some reason you get a [chunked HTTP transfer](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.41), then just [set the progress bar to be indeterminate](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSProgressIndicator_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000114-setIndeterminate_), since that's the whole point of a chunked transfer (that you don't know how big it's going to be).